# SwiftUI custom error with additional detail for support/tracking

Tags: swiftui, error-handling

I want to track additional information about errors to help support issues and be proactive where errors/bugs are encountered. I am new to iOS/Swift, but I have followed a few YouTube videos and posts on error handling to alert users of an error ([this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mb2y5JWYo5I) was the most up to date/best one I found) but I also want to provide more detail as well to help support. I created a custom error:

```
enum CustomError: Error {
    
    case apiDecodingError
    ...
}
```

and extended it:

```
extension CustomError: LocalizedError {

    var errorDescription: String? {
        switch self {
          case .apiDecodingError:
            return NSLocalizedString("Problem understanding service response.", comment: "")
         ...
        }
    }
}
```

but I cannot add additional properties to the extension because: `Extensions must not contain stored properties`.

When I catch and throw a custom error from, for example, decoding the response of an api call:

```
    } catch let DecodingError.keyNotFound(key, context) {
        print("Key '\(key)' not found:", context.debugDescription)
        print("codingPath:", context.codingPath)
        throw CustomError.DecodingError
```

This makes for a simplified user message:

[image]

but I also want to send the detail to the bug tracking system with the specific problem, such as the key which was having the problem.

```
            } catch {
                print("\(error)")
                
                let properties = ["Error" : error.localizedDescription]
                Analytics.trackEvent("UpdateNotificationSetting", withProperties: properties, flags: .critical)
                isAlertErrorPresented = true
                errorAlert = ErrorAlert(error: error)
            }
```

I would like to send along the detail but that means the custom error needs additional information from the inner error. I'm a novice at SwiftUI, is there a standard way to address this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by expanding `CustomError`

```
enum CustomError: LocalizedError{
    ///Takes in any error and makes it compatible with `LocalizedError`
    case error(Error)
    ///Allows for throwing an error with a custom description
    case custom(description: String, failureReason: String? = nil, helpAnchor: String? = nil, recoverySuggestion: String? = nil)
    ///Can be used as a custom key using localization features
    case customKey
    ///Mimic your decoding error
    case apiDecodingError(key: String, path: String)
    
    var errorDescription: String?{
        switch self{
        case .error(let error):
            return error.localizedDescription
        case .custom(let description, _ , _, _):
            return description
        case .apiDecodingError(let key, path: let path):
            return String(format: "Key %@ not found: codingPath: %@", key, path)
        default:
            ///Add `customKeyErrorDescription` to Localizable.strings
            return NSLocalizedString("\(self)" + "ErrorDescription", comment: "AppError")
        }
    }
    var failureReason: String?{
        switch self{
        case .error(let error):
            let nsError = error as NSError
            return nsError.localizedFailureReason
        case .custom(_ , let failureReason , _, _):
            return failureReason
        case .apiDecodingError(_, _):
            return nil
        default:
            ///Add `customKeyFailureReason` to Localizable.strings
            return NSLocalizedString("\(self)" + "FailureReason", comment: "AppError")
        }
    }
    var helpAnchor: String?{
        switch self{
        case .error(let error):
            let nsError = error as NSError
            return nsError.helpAnchor
        case .custom(_ , _ , let helpAnchor, _):
            return helpAnchor
        case .apiDecodingError(_, _):
            return nil
        default:
            ///Add `customKeyHelpAnchor` to Localizable.strings
            return NSLocalizedString("\(self)" + "HelpAnchor", comment: "AppError")
        }
    }
    var recoverySuggestion: String?{
        switch self{
        case .error(let error):
            let nsError = error as NSError
            return nsError.localizedRecoverySuggestion
        case .custom(_, _ , _, let recoverySuggestion):
            return recoverySuggestion
        case .apiDecodingError(_, _):
            return nil
        default:
            ///Add `customKeyRecoverySuggestion` to Localizable.strings
            return NSLocalizedString("\(self)" + "RecoverySuggestion", comment: "AppError")
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can pass along any standard error

```
do{

}catch{
    CustomError.error(error)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I realize I need to add a few types of decoding error (data corrupt, key not found, data not found, type mismatch) but I think this will work for all of them if I create separate errors for each.

Comment: It seems like you've used this model.  My .alert with error: uses the errorDescription in the dialog. I think I need to keep that simple for the user, but pass along more detail to the bug system. What did you use? failureReason?

Comment: Maybe I could add a properties property ([String:String]?) as well since that's what I end up sending up to the bug tracking system.

Comment: @Icj any of those options should work. I personally like keeping everything in the original Error and then parse at the very end for my purposes. `error. errorDescription` is usually sufficient for a user.

Comment: Does that mean you would handle the apiDecodingError differently?

Comment: Yes, I would just use the `.error(error)` and send the whole thing.

Comment: So essentially the apiDecodingError(let key, path: let path) from the catch would be in the CustomError enum. I’m not sure what that would look like. That would make total sense.

Comment: My debugProperties: [String:String]? isn't working because it gets to the first switch/case .error and doesn't call the .apiDecodingError one. Looks like on the others the .error gets triggered and then the .[whatever] does.

The other way could be cleaner if I figure it out, but in one scenario (.serverError which I throw when I get a 500 response back) and don't know how to pass in the URL or at least LastPathComponent.

Comment: I put a print statement in each case of the `var failureReason` and it prints `.error` and `.apiServerError` when called. Why is it being called twice? I'm trying to create a function to pass errors to a bug tracker with detail, but it only catches `.error` and not the more detailed one I wanted.